# How do I use hashcat to recover password from ata drive lock

Tags: disk-encryption, hashcat

How would I get the password for encrypted SSD's I bought (legally bought from a business who forgot the password, I plan on wiping them after I unlock them) I am new to using software like hashcat, I tried finding the hardware reset key hut these drives are old so They don't have a code I can use to factory reset it, I have a relatively strong system with a 7th gen i7 and a 6gb 1060 so I should be able to do it.

Comment: Make? Model? Probably more info needed to get good help here.

Comment: kingston ssdnow 300V

Comment: See if there is a tool available from the MFR to reset the password. Otherwise I suspect you have purchased a nice bunch of bricks.

Comment: sorry but could I ask what mfr is?

Comment: Manufacturer. Kingston.

Comment: Brendan: Did Royce's answer work for you?

Answer (score 4):

No need for hashcat. From my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1299282/my-crucial-ssd-is-locked-after-an-erase-attempt-and-cant-seem-unlock-even-with/1299308#1299308):

> [...] at the ATA Secure Erase level, you should be able to initiate a
> new erase with a new master password, regardless of what the old
> password *was*.

This destroys all existing data, as designed by the ATA Secure Erase specification. But once it's done, you can then use the drive again.